# Relational Database Design - Oracle Apex 5.0

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm looking for a way to efficiently create related databases in Oracle Apex. Here's what I'm doing which is why i'm having issues properly designing a DB layout:

We have associate statistics at my company. There are over 90 associates, on multiple teams. Each team has different metrics for their associates. Like amount of calls they take, documents processed (around 10 for one team, and 60 for another).

So far I have created the following tables:

```
Teams - Contains associates names and relevant info such as manager, title, etc. 
Team1_Metrics - Contains all metrics for specific team (have 2 other tables similar to this)
Manager - Contains columns for data a manager can enter for an associate
General_Stats - Contains general data for all associates like calls, etc
```

In my Apex application I will be building a form where a specific person can go in and add this data for select associates for certain dates. In each table I have added a `RCD_Date` field and `EMP_ID` field mainly for primary keys.

How would I go about building a relationship between these tables. When I create a master form with details I need them to all see the same data. The problem is I also need to ensure the application allows the associate entering the data to select a date for the entry. This way we can build reports that say "On 04/15/17 here is your statistics".

Thanks

Comment: So as far as I understand this question, there are actually 2. The main one  being a question of modeling your data. And I want to stress it: your datamodel is extremely important. A bad model will result in a bad application and a high probability of bad performance. Don't just think it, draw it. Use Oracle's datamodeler to draw the tables and their relations. Building the apex application will come rather naturally when you have a model that makes sense and doesn't make you go through hoops.

Comment: @Tom I will use the datamodeler to get together the processes and their relationships. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data modeling is a core, crucial skill for any sw developer, per @Tom.
I suggest learning how to create a good data model. The best book I know is Entity Relationship Modeling, [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201416964), used for .049.
I also suggest this [link](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html), starting with # 3 How to Model Data.

If all you want to do is create two (or whatever) tables and foreign keys, you can do so in APEX in the SQL Workshop > Object Browser, docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35128/GUID-26210AD4-7C96-4D10-8FB8-09BF3787BD98.htm#AEUTL101).

Comment: Thank you @Joe I actually ordered all 3 books in the series. This is exactly what I was looking for, and being new to this I just wasn't sure which route to take. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. If this is an option for you, I am teaching a 4 day data modeling online "Live Virtual Class" starting May 15th. You are welcome and encouraged to attend.  More info can be found https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=609&get_params=dc:D56497,clang:EN.

Comment: Another super fun thing is Oracle Quick SQL, which was released very recently. It's easy and fast, and allows very very quick prototyping or creation of the basic datamodel. https://apex.oracle.com/en/quicksql/

Comment: Wow. The quick sql is pretty slick. Thanks!

Comment: But be careful - tools like this make it easy to quickly create bad designs while giving the impression you have created something good. Over time - or even quickly, bad designs will kill you,  The tools are not the challenge - a good, stable design is the goal. We used to call giving tools like these to people who are inexperienced about good design "giving monkeys hand grenades" - present company excepted, of course ;-)